# How to store an attribute of all input(checkbox) elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-structures, element

I am trying to store the **name** attribute of all the checkboxes in a page, in some sort of array/data structure.

How do I go about doing this?

```
<input name="sample" type="checkbox" value="" align="left" />
<input name="sample2" type="checkbox" value="" align="left" />
```

The name attribute will be unique. Any idea on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get properties of a set of elements and into an array, like this:

```
var arr = $("input[type=checkbox]").map(function() { return this.name; }).get();
```

There are slimmer selectors, like `input:checkbox` or even `:checkbox`, but they are *much* slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
var store_them_here = [];
$(':checkbox').each(function(i, e) {
    store_them_here.push($(e).attr('name'));
})
```

Comment: interesting, I will use this if the above doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var result_array = [];
jQuery(':checkbox').each( function(index, Element){
  result_array.push(jQuery(this).attr('name'));
})
```